# How to set Badge Value in CustomTabbarItem

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, uitabbaritem

I am using a `CustomTabbarItem` and I want to implement the `badge` Value on the specific `tabbarItem`. Can anyone help me and provide me code, so that I put it in my `customTabbar`. I am new in `Iphone`, so feel free to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think you use this code...For help

```
[[self navigationController] tabBarItem].badgeValue = @"0";
```

If You want Complete Implement Project then [DownLoad](http://www.allappsdevelopers.com/TopicDetail.aspx?TopicID=09a77314-625d-40cf-8363-02f96dd294dd)

Comment: Please re-read the question again. I have asked the complete implementation of badgeValue as in UITabbarItem.